# For loop and sign operator, reading Java

Tags: java

I'm tutoring a high school student and my CS language skills need help.

How do you interpret this java code?

```
Int k;
For (k=0; k < nums.length; k++) {
       nums [k] -= sign (nums [k]);
       nums [k] += sign (nums [k]);
}
```

In the instructions it says that `int [] nums= {-2,-1,0,1,2}`. It also says
 `int sign(int x)` returns 1 if positive and -1 if negative and 0 if x is 0.

I suppose I need to understand what happens in the code where "-" and "=" are next to each other. And also what happens when "+" and "=" are next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The compound assignment operation

```
   nums [k] -= sign (nums [k]);
   nums [k] += sign (nums [k]);
```

is the same as

```
nums [k] = nums [k] - sign (nums [k]);
nums [k] = nums [k] + sign (nums [k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first operation in the loop,

`nums [k] -= sign (nums [k]);`

Will subtract 1 from a positive number and add 1 to a negative number.  In effect, moving the number "one closer" to zero.  (or decreasing its absolute value by 1)

The second operation in the loop

`nums [k] += sign (nums [k]);`

Will add 1 to a positive number and subtract one from a negative number, increasing its absolute value by 1.

So, to an casual glance, the code does nothing except waste CPU cycles.  :-)

However, there are subtleties.

1. If the number is 1 or -1, it will get moved towards zero, and become 0.  In that case, the second step will **do nothing**, and will **not** reverse the action.  In other words, this code is a very obscure and inefficient way of converting 1 and -1 to 0.
2. If there is an integer overflow or underflow (a number is Integer.MAXINT) then interesting stuff happens - this is left as an exercise to the reader.  Since your inputs are small integers this doesn't apply to you exact case.